# Multiple REPLACE functions inside LIKE comparison query in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working in Oracle environment.
I need to build query that would search through badly formatted telephone data.
So far I got :

```
select * from guest_db
REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(TEL1, '[[:space:]]*',''),'+',NULL),')',NULL),'(',NULL
LIKE '% 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REXEXP_REPLACE('(0)1111 111111','[[:space:]]*',''),'+',NULL),')',NULL)'(',NULL)
||%';
```

difficulty is putting second  nested replace(replace function between '% %' signs without turning them into strings. If I build this function without those percentage signs LIKE function behaves like equal sign. It spits back only exact match ( obviously without special characters like ),(, +, , )...
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: By "search through" do you mean only find them? Do you also want to fix them? If you want to fix them, can you also describe what makes the phone number valid - for example 999-999-9999 or whatever.

Comment: can u give some sample data and expected o/p

Comment: If I put 111 I want to return records like 0-5555-111 as well as 111 111 111. If you put 111 in this query it will return only exact match 111 even though it has LIKE.

Comment: OK, solved I had to concate function with '%'|| replace(replace(... ||'%' and jump out of the string. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved I had to concate function with '%'|| replace(replace(... ||'%' and jump out of the string